# What is the best way to present a list of images in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I want  to load a number of images into a widget that will show me the images in a list. 
It can be many images so it needs to be fast, also I'd like to attach a check box for each image presented.
What will be the best way to implement it in Qt 4.6?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you want a `QListView` where each item in the list is composed of an image and a check box.  If this is correct, then per [QListView Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qlistview.html), you can have only icons for images.  I'm thinking that this is why you are asking the question.

What you could do is use [QTableView](http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/qtableview.html) instead.  You can style the table to look like a list box.  And each item in the table can contain an image and a checkbox.  To see how to add images to an item line, see the [Pixelator Example](http://doc.qt.io/archives/4.6/itemviews-pixelator.html).  Based on personal experience, you may want to use the example as the starting point for your code.  I've found this works the best for me.

The Checkboxes are a standard option for a column in the table.

Answer (score 1):

use Qlistview in icon mode and in the paint delegate handle the drawing part of tick mark.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest create html document and dispaly it using `QtWebKit`. It seems to be the easiest way.

Here your can find some examples
http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/examples-webkit.html